# Permutations of 7, replacing one field at a time

Tags: sql, permutation

[image]

I don't even know how to name this topic.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have sets of data that I have to process and they might have a few versions of the same field.

For example, I have a data set that comes in with the following columns:

```
FacilityName
FacilityAlias
TIN
TIN2
NPI
NPI2
NPI3
MailingAddress
MailingCity, State (they're given to me as 2 different fields but for my needs they're counted as 1)
MailingZIP
BillingAddress
Billing City, State
BillingZIP
```

my final dataset will only have the columns below

```
FacilityName
TIN
NPI
Address
CityState
ZIP
```

but I have to make sure I have a row for each possible combination of the fields,
so I have to create the following queries:

```
INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP) SELECT FacilityName, TIN, NPI. BillingAddress, BillingCityState, BillingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;

INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP) SELECT FacilityAlias, TIN, NPI. BillingAddress, BillingCityState, BillingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;

INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP) SELECT FacilityName, TIN, NPI. MailingAddress, MailingCityState, MailingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;

INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP) SELECT FacilityName, TIN2, NPI. BillingAddress, BillingCityState, BillingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;

INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP) SELECT FacilityAlias, TIN2, NPI. BillingAddress, BillingCityState, BillingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;

INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP) SELECT FacilityName, TIN2, NPI. MailingAddress, MailingCityState, MailingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;
```

and so on.

How is this done?

Comment: for the love of god fix your formatting.

Comment: Umesh,  thank you for fixing my post :) I apologize, I don't know how to format code well here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite difficult to give the exact answer as I'm not 100% sure why you're doing this.

But an easy way to use sql to return a set of multiple permutation is to create a query that returns a cartisian product.

e.g.
    select a,b,c from
    (select 1 a union select 2 a union select 3 a) 
    (select 10 b union select 20 b union select 30 b) 
    (select 100 c union select 200 union select 300 c)

notice no joins.  the sub queries could be distinct queries from the matchprep table.
in this example the results would look like

```
1,10,100
1,10,300
1,10,300
...
...
3,30,100
3,30,200
3,30,300
```

You could then insert the return data set.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

EDIT:

This has to be it :)

```
select  
name, tin, npi, address, state, zip
from (select distinct name from (select FacilityName as name from matchprep 
    union select FacilityAlias as name from matchprep) f cross join
(select distinct tin (select TIN as tin from matchprep 
    union select TIN2 as tin from matchprep)) t cross join
 (select distinct NPI from matchprep) n cross join
 (select distinct address,state,zip from (select BillingAddress as address, BillingCityState as state, BillingZIP as zip from matchprep 
    union select MailingAddress as address, MailingCityState as state, MailingZIP as zip from matchprep)) a
```

Based on your example inserts, Mailing address details and Billing address details are always distinct from each other.

FacilityName and Alias will be one permutation.
Tin and Tin2 will be another
You'll get a cartesian product of for each NPI.

Comment: i don't think it's this easy. i hope i'm wrong though. i'm doing this because i have a matching database that matches one data set against another. the sets i get to match will sometimes have 2 versions of the same field, for example, they will give me a list that will have 2 columns with TINs and 2 columns with NPIs. so i have to make sure all the data they gave me will have a row available for matching. i'm open to any suggestions, i thought this was the only way of doing it except running the match once for every extra field.

Comment: let me play with this idea, but i've been at it for 3 days and i'm afraid it's not this easy. thank you in any case))))))))

Comment: i don't know if this is the best answer, but your original one is the one i was able to use for my needs. sorry everyone else if you think i chose the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all possible combinations of the 7 fields.  For this, use `cross join`:

```
select  FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP
from (select distinct FacilityName from matchprep) f cross join
     (select distinct TIN from matchprep) t cross join
     (select distinct NPI from matchprep) n cross join
     (select distinct Address from matchprep) a cross join
     (select distinct CityState from matchprep) c cross join
     (select distinct ZIP from matchprep) z
```

Comment: let me try this and if this is not the answer then i'm explaining this wrong. i will then create an excel sheet with examples and upload. thank you both of you for trying!!!!

Comment: no, this is not it. i'm about to update the original question with an excel file. thank you for even trying :)

Comment: yes, thats right, cross join in ansi sql (had oracle hat on) - principal is the same. you want a cartesian product of each distinct field in your query. to get `FacilityName`and `FacilityAlias` in same field, you should `select distinct n from (select FacilityName as n from matchprep union select FacilityAlias as n from matchprep))`. The database you're using would be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

I assume you covered all the permutations with the example inserts at the end of the question and that you don't also need to include NPI2 and NPI3 as permutations for NPI. In which case several inserts as you've written should work but it would be simpler to combine these into a single insert statement using UNION e.g.

```
INSERT INTO MATCH ( FacilityName, TIN, NPI, Address, CityState, ZIP)
SELECT FacilityName, TIN, NPI. BillingAddress, BillingCityState, BillingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;
UNION
SELECT FacilityAlias, TIN, NPI. BillingAddress, BillingCityState, BillingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;
UNION 
SELECT FacilityName, TIN, NPI. MailingAddress, MailingCityState, MailingZIP FROM MATCHPREP;
etc.
```

Or have i misunderstood the question?

Comment: no, i didn't cover them all)))) NPI2 and NPI3 need to be included. and this is a fake example, i'm trying to come up with code that will do this for any data set i ever get. i never know what i will get, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

just for reference, below is the version i was able to use

```
     SELECT A0.*
    ,a1.*
    ,a2.*
    ,a8.*
FROM (SELECT 'FacilityName' C1 FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'TIN' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'NPI' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'Address' FROM DUAL) a0
    ,(SELECT 'FacilityName1' C2 FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'TIN1' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'NPI1' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'Address1' FROM DUAL) a1
    ,(SELECT 'FacilityName2' C3 FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'TIN2' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'NPI2' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'Address2' FROM DUAL) a2
    ,(SELECT 'FacilityName3' C4 FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'TIN3' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'NPI3' FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 'Address3' FROM DUAL) a8
  WHERE   (   c1 LIKE 'FacilityName%'
       OR c2 LIKE 'FacilityName%'
       OR c3 LIKE 'FacilityName%'
       OR c4 LIKE 'FacilityName%')
     AND (   c1 LIKE 'TIN%'
       OR c2 LIKE 'TIN%'
       OR c3 LIKE 'TIN%'
       OR c4 LIKE 'TIN%')
     AND (   c1 LIKE 'NPI%'
       OR c2 LIKE 'NPI%'
       OR c3 LIKE 'NPI%'
       OR c4 LIKE 'NPI%')
     AND (   c1 LIKE 'Address%'
       OR c2 LIKE 'Address%'
       OR c3 LIKE 'Address%'
       OR c4 LIKE 'Address%')
```